# Is there any way to download shared remote file in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby, dropbox

I am a Ruby on Rails developer.

I want to download a shared remote file in Ruby on Rails.
The file is in another's Dropbox folder.

I know

`dl = 1`: force file to download in browser

`raw = 1`: force file to get the raw content

I have tried in 2 ways.

```
open('tmp/file.csv', 'wb') do |file|
  file << open('https://www.dropbox.com/s/xyz/file.CSV?dl=1').read
end
```

```
require 'csv'
require 'open-uri'

csv_text = open('https://www.dropbox.com/s/xyz/file.CSV?dl=1')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers=>true)
csv.each do |row|
  puts row
end
```

**The file is created but the created file is empty.**

I have tried with **raw=1** in the URL but the result was the same.

Anyone can help?

Comment: "No luck" is not very descriptive of your problem. You must at least show some code for others to be able to help you.

Comment: Please post your actual code for downloading via API or URL, along with any return values, exceptions, or errors. Otherwise, you're asking people to guess at what's going on.

Comment: "no luck" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Comment: @Eyeslandic, it is updated.

Comment: @NikolaCojcic It's better, I voted to reopen, let's see what happens

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs, I have added the code I used.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I have added the code I used. Can you please help me to fix it?